# What would be the voltage difference between two phases shorted together and the third phase?

Tags: mains, three-phase, voltage-measurement

I understand that it would be catastrophic for the two phases shorted together.
Say the line to neutral voltage is 2 volts and line to line voltage is √3×2 volts.

Comment: Well, to find "middle between two phases", you could use two like resistors as a voltage divider or a 1:1 transformer. Or use a 1:1 isolation transformer "to put them in series". Draw vectors.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the propertys of the source in question.

**If you assume:**

- R1..3 to be the source impedances (50Hz also has complex components)
- R4 is infinite
- The phase-difference is 120 degrees exactly:
- And V1..V3 to be equal

Then VM4 will show your normal "line potential delta ", e.g. sqrt(3)*V1

**If you assume:**

- R4 is 0 (Short)

Then, due to R1 and R2 there will still be a potential different from GND/PE on the Points L1/L2. This potential also has a phase different from L1/L2/L3. Therefore, L3-L2 voltage will not be "normal line potential delta".

**In conclusion:**

- In an academic world i suggest deriving the equations from the circuit shown below.
- In an real world AC-Mains scenario: Some fuse will blow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f15wDA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>